# Android Webview Performance differences

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I am writing a webview app in android 4.4.3 the latest Android version.
But my biggest Problem is the performance differences between the chrome browser and my webview app.
The differences are huge.

How can I get the webview app to the same performance as the chrome browser?

Comment: Shouldnt the webview and the chrome browser are on the same code base? There shouldnt be a difference.

Comment: this is not showing any result still its slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. It will help you in **increasing the speed** -

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Also try adding this to **Manifest** under desired activity -

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

**EDIT**

Chrome does not use webview - [source](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_this_mean_chrome_for_android_is_using_the_webview_).

> **Does this mean Chrome for Android is using the WebView?**
>
> No, Chrome for Android is separate from WebView. They're both based on the same code, including a common JavaScript engine and rendering engine.

That is probably the only reason for the performance difference

Comment: I did both but with no real difference in speeds. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I don't think there's much what you can do about it. Is your internet connection fast enough?

Comment: yep it is really fast in the chrome android browser. but not in the webview which should be based on the chrome android browser

Comment: @Aryan  this is not showing any result still its slow